# Getting "An unexpected error occurred while preparing endpoint: C-9999" while (second generation) packaging this morning

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, gack, spring24

Anyone else getting this gack error today when creating a managed package version?

> An unexpected error occurred while preparing endpoint: C-9999.  Please contact Salesforce Support and provide the following error code: 768983807-69679 (-1143416155)

Same package was working fine last week so I'm hoping it is a temporary error related to Spring '24 rollout.

Comment: I have same one when creating scratch org... on few devhubs

Comment: I'm getting the same error attempting to create a new package version via SF CLI.. I guess package development is just completely halted until this bug is resolved?

Comment: Hi @smohyee, Yes and as below's answer says scratch org creation is broken too more than just packaging. Hopefully means that the work to fix the problem will have high priority as it impacts many.

Comment: Just a quick note, 1st generation package versions can be still created (2nd gen pkg versions are still broken).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug most probably introduced with the update to Spring '24 and affects also the creation of scratch orgs.

Salesforce has just identified it as a multi-customer concern and confirmed it as bug. It can be found here:

https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000yx0wjAAA/

I've also opened a [bug](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/2703#issuecomment-1938748847) in sfdx cli github project in case this wasn't recognized by Salesforce (I think it will be soon closed).